# how to create a template in XSL-FO for a table with changing no. of rows to generate a PDF?

Tags: xsl-fo

I am a newbie  to XSL-FO wants to know that how to  generate a PDF for balance sheet. So how should i create a template for that in XSL-FO as the no. of rows in the balance sheet table will vary according to the user record in the particular time duration. The records for balance sheet is coming from the API call in Java . I  just need a guidance how to create a Template in XSL-FO with variable number of rows as per user records.

Simple Example is to generate a PDF for a user having an account in any bank . The PDF will contains the transaction history of that user of previous months in a tabular format. So the no. of records in the table may vary in accordance to the no. of transaction done by different users.

And the transaction List is coming through a JAVA API call  which contains the records which need to be populated into TEMPLATE which is to created in XSl-FO.  So how that dynamic data is populated with variable no. of rows in XSL-FO ?????? An example will help

Thanks in advance

Comment: post an example input and what you have tried. Without showing any input or expected output you question cannot even be addressed

Answer (score -1):

First, you must generate an xml document with all the data you want in your PDF. for instance:

```
<userData>
   <id>1234</id>
   <firstName>John</firstName>
   <lastName>Doe</lastName>
   ...
   <balance>3526.35</balance>
   <scripture>
       <date>2017-02-20<date>
       <label>Online payment to Amazon.com</label>
       <amount>-92.25</amount>
   </scripture>
   <scripture>
       <date>2017-01-27<date>
       <label>Salary</label>
       <amount>12000</label>
   </scripture>
   ...
</userData>
```

Then you must write an XSL-FO template that will take such a structure as input. for instance:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:template match="userData">
        <fo:root>
            <fo:layout-master-set>
                <fo:simple-page-master master-name="only"
                        page-width="21cm" page-height="29.7cm"
                        margin-top="2.5cm" margin-bottom="1.5cm"
                        margin-left="4.5cm" margin-right="2.5cm">
                    <fo:region-body/>
                    <fo:region-after extent="1cm"/>
                </fo:simple-page-master>
            </fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:page-sequence master-reference="only">
                <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                    <fo:wrapper font-size="12pt" 
                            font-family="Arial, Geneva, Helvetica, sans-serif">
                        <fo:block font-weight="bold" space-before="1.5cm">
                            ID: <xsl:value-of select="id/text()"/>
                        </fo:block>
                        <fo:block font-weight="bold">
                            User: <xsl:value-of select="lastName/text()"/>, <xsl:value-of select="firstName/text()"/>
                        </fo:block>
                        <fo:block font-weight="bold">
                            Balance: <xsl:value-of select="balance/text()"/>
                        </fo:block>
                        <fo:table table-layout="fixed"
                                space-before="1.5cm"
                                space-after="1.5cm">
                            <fo:table-column column-width="2cm"/>
                            <fo:table-column column-width="5.5cm"/>
                            <fo:table-column column-width="5cm"/>
                            <fo:table-body>
                                <fo:table-row>
                                    <fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:block font-weight="bold">
                                            Date
                                        </fo:block>
                                    </fo:table-cell>
                                    <fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:block font-weight="bold">
                                            Label
                                        </fo:block>
                                    </fo:table-cell>
                                    <fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:block font-weight="bold">
                                            Amount
                                        </fo:block>
                                    </fo:table-cell>
                                </fo:table-row>
                                <xsl:for-each select="scripture">
                                    <fo:table-row>
                                        <fo:table-cell>
                                            <fo:block>
                                                <xsl:value-of select="date/text()"/>
                                            </fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:table-cell>
                                            <fo:block>
                                                <xsl:value-of select="label/text()"/>
                                            </fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:table-cell>
                                            <fo:block>
                                                <xsl:value-of select="amount/text()"/>
                                            </fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                    </fo:table-row>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </fo:table-body>
                        </fo:table>
                    </fo:wrapper>
                </fo:flow>
            </fo:page-sequence>
        </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks @Maurice  but this doesn't answers to my question.  the Number. of rows are  based on transaction record for that user  which may be any number. So how to populate that data.

Comment: @tarun In the example, I have called them scripture. There can be any number of them per user record.

Comment: I am getting my data as a HashMap from the JAVA code . I want to covert that hashMAp into a table. Only using Xsl:fo without using Xml . Is there any way to figure this out .

Comment: @tarun you can use another template engine; velocity for instance.